# Can I install the Cinnamon DE on Ubuntu GNOME? If so, how?

Tags: desktop-environments, ubuntu-gnome, cinnamon

First, I would like to know if I can install the Cinnamon DE without messing up Ubuntu GNOME.

Second, I would like to know how to install the Cinnamon DE.

Lastly, I would like to know how I would access Cinnamon after installing.

Comment: What version of Ubuntu is this?

Comment: Ubuntu GNOME 17.04

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. To Install, use:

   ```
   sudo add-apt-repository ppa:embrosyn/cinnamon
   sudo apt update
   sudo apt install cinnamon blueberry
   ```
2. Steps to remove Cinnamon from the system:

   - Completely remove Cinnamon 3.0

     ```
     sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/embrosyn-cinnamon*.list
     sudo apt purge cinnamon* libcinnamon* nemo* libnemo-extension1 cjs libcjs0e blueberry gir1.2-cinnamondesktop-3.0 gir1.2-meta-muffin-0.0 libmuffin0 muffin-common
     sudo apt autoremove
     ```
   - Purge the PPA

     ```
     sudo apt install ppa-purge
     sudo ppa-purge ppa:embrosyn/cinnamon
     ```

Known issues:

In Ubuntu 16.04, Ambiance and Radiance themes have some issues in Cinnamon, like missing shadows for CSD apps.

- Fix:

  ```
  sudo apt install numix-gtk-theme
  ```

After installtion logout and choose cinnamon desktop from login screen.

Source:

http://www.webupd8.org/2016/04/how-to-install-cinnamon-30-in-ubuntu.html

https://launchpad.net/~embrosyn/+archive/ubuntu/cinnamon